# Rank function to rank 0 as 0, apply a function to elements of vector with certain values?

Tags: r, rank

I would like to rank a vector with the rank() function. 
However, I require values that=0 to return a rank that=0, and then for the ranking to continue at 1 for the element with the lowest value...

Example:

```
a<-c(0, 0:5, 0)
rank(a, ties.method="first")
```

(Undesired) output:

```
[1] 1 2 4 5 6 7 3
```

Desired output would look like:

```
[1] 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 0
```

I imagine the solution looks something like applying a ranking function only to elements of vector(a) that (don't) have the value 0

Comment: Maybe also `dplyr::dense_rank(a) - 1` Though that assumes you have zeros in the vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `rank` the elements excluding the 0 values and replace the values in the corresponding elements in the vector by the new `rank` vector.

```
 a1 <- a
 a1[a1!=0] <- rank(a1[a1!=0])
 a1
```

Or we can do this in a single step with `replace`.

```
replace(a, a!=0, rank(a[a!=0]))
```

Comment: This answer gives the desired output:
`[1] 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 0`